# How can I show different time depending on the user's local time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I do have the setting just like this

**config/application.rb**

```
config.time_zone = 'London'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
```

All the time will be saved with London's local time.
However, my application will be used from everywhere in the world so that I want to show with their local time.

How can I make it possible?

P.S. I've watched this, but it seems it would work only if the user is a membership of Rails app.
It won't know their local time unless the person who's seeing do register and set his local time.

Isn't there any technique to obtain the timezone of the visitor's PC and calculate UTC time with it?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?autoplay=true

Comment: May be this gem https://github.com/cleverua/client_timezone_detection can help you.

Comment: @SybariteManoj I've installed that and put this `<%= javascript_include_tz_detection %>` in layouts/application.rb

Comment: @SybariteManoj No. It shows the same time even if I change OS's timezone:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to convert the time according to user's local timezone. Here is what I did:

In ApplicationHelper.rb, add a method that generate the html that will invoke javascript at the client's browser:

```
def localize(time)
    "<script type='text/javascript'>localize(#{time.tv_sec * 1000});</script>".html_safe
end
```

Add the javascript function that will process the time and display its string format (using the browser's timezone)

```
function localize(millisec)
{
  var d = new Date(millisec);
  document.write(d.toString());
}
```

Then in your views, when you need to display the time, call the helper method:

```
<span><%= localize(@my_record.time) %></span>
```